# Fade in original element without displaying secondary one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setInterval(function () {
    $(".story1").fadeOut(2000,function(){
          $(".story2").fadeIn(2000, function(){
              $(".story2").fadeOut(2000)
          });
      })
    });
```

That is the code I have. `story1` is already displayed on the page when loaded, and what I am trying to do is get it to fade out from `story1` to `story2` and then fade out `story2` back into fading in `story1` (So there's an endless loop of `story1` fading out into `story2` and that fading out into `story1` again etc. A bit like a carousal, goes from `1` to `2` to `3` then back to `1` again)

However, when `story1` fades out and `story2` fades in, it just keeps fading out and fading in to `story2` over and over again. I'm not sure how to correct this?

Comment: You need to provide MCVE (or at least relevant HTML markup) in order to get specific answer

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to future-proof things like this, for example if you wanted to add a third story later, you'd be able to do so very easily with this code:

```js
var r = 0, stories = $(".stories").children();
setInterval(function () {
  r = (r+1) % stories.length;
  
  stories.fadeOut(2000);
  stories.eq(r).stop().fadeIn(2000);
}, 5000);
```

```css
.stories {
  position: relative;
}
.story {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.story:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stories">
 <div class="story story1">lorem ipsum</div>
 <div class="story story2">dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Not only is the code shorter this way, but it will work no matter how many stories there are (except zero, but that's an error anyway). Feel free to test it with three stories, or fifty!

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function () {
    
  if( $('.story.active').is(':last-child') ) {
    var nextStory = $('.story:first-child');
    
    $('.story.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(500);
    $(nextStory).addClass('active').delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
  }
  else {
    var nextStory = $('.story.active').next();
    
    $('.story.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(500);
    $(nextStory).addClass('active').delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
  }
  
}, 3000);
```

```css
.story:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stories">
  <div class="story active">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="story">dolor sit amet 2</div>
  <div class="story">dolor sit amet 3</div>
  <div class="story">dolor sit amet 4</div>
  <div class="story">dolor sit amet 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your interval delay is shorter than the animations ones

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without setting the `position: absolute`

Comment: @NickDeJaeger I see. Would this be extensible i.e. if a third `story` was introduced?

Comment: @djones1984 Here you go (edited post) An upvote would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function init(){
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var first = $(".story1").is(":visible")?1:2;
    var second = first%2 + 1;
     $(".story" + first).fadeToggle(2000, function(){
       $(".story" + second).fadeToggle(2000);
     }); 
  }, 4000);
}

init();
```

```css
.tile{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding:10px;
}

.story1{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.story2{
  display:none;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #333
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile story1">Story 1
</div>
<div class="tile story2">Story 2
</div>
```

Comment: What is `transform:2s` exactly?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for pointing it out. Have removed it. My initial though was to have animation with css and not jQuery. so used animation class. Have updated my answer